# Django prefetch_related on an implicit relation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-database

Let's say that I'm making an address book app.

```
class AddressBookEntry(models.Model):
    address_book = models.ForeignKey(AddressBook)
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Both of these objects have an email field. Now I want to find all the address books that a given
user appears in. So I make a method on User like

```
    def entries(self):
        return AddressBookEntry.objects.filter(email=self.email)
```

That works fine, but when I'm fetching a few users I need to execute a DB query once per user. I'd
like to do `User.objects.all().prefetch_related('entries')`, but this doesn't work as `entries` is a
method, not a ForeignKey.

So-

- is there a way to somehow tell django that there's a relationship here without explicitly having
  a many-to-many field with its through table, so I can use select_related?
- or is there a way to do the JOIN between the objects when I fetch the users (this would be a 
  cross join I think, but it would be better than what I've got now.)

Comment: Is this a legacy database that you can't change? If not, why don't you just make the `email` field in `AddressBookEntry` a M2M relation to `User` instead?

Comment: The email in `AddressBookEntry` is input by the user, they can enter email addresses of people who are not users of the app.

Comment: Please add the `AddressBookEntries` model definition to your post. Why do you have both an `AddressBookEntries` model and an `AddressBookEntry` model? That seems strange.

Comment: @garbanzio sorry, that was a typo. I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 0):

The more 'Django' way to do it would be to have an explicit relation field:

```
class AddressBookEntry(models.Model):
    address_book = models.ForeignKey(AddressBook)
    name = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="entries")

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()

User.objects.all().select_related('entries')
```